# Is BTRFS saying that my HDD is dead?

Tags: hard-disk, btrfs, io

I noticed that my HP N54L was laboring and discovered that `dmesg` was reporting this:

```
[   81.945530] btrfs read error corrected: ino 1 off 16685977600 (dev /dev/sdb sector 2636776)
[   82.010023] btrfs read error corrected: ino 1 off 16637734912 (dev /dev/sdb sector 2589656)

[   85.927604] verify_parent_transid: 43 callbacks suppressed
[   85.927615] parent transid verify failed on 16956989440 wanted 13182 found 12799
[   85.974600] parent transid verify failed on 16585043968 wanted 13145 found 12357

[   89.903548] repair_io_failure: 26 callbacks suppressed
[   89.903560] btrfs read error corrected: ino 1 off 16875483136 (dev /dev/sdb sector 2821816)
[  115.951579] parent transid verify failed on 16963846144 wanted 13184 found 12802
[  115.976830] btrfs read error corrected: ino 1 off 16963846144 (dev /dev/sdb sector 2908128)
[  115.988907] parent transid verify failed on 16978874368 wanted 13187 found 12815

[  543.848294] btrfs: device fsid e8f8fc09-3aae-4fce-85ca-fcf7665b9f02 devid 2 transid 13199 /dev/sdb
[ 1120.854825] verify_parent_transid: 5 callbacks suppressed
[ 1120.854838] parent transid verify failed on 16956600320 wanted 13184 found 12799

[ 1120.891229] repair_io_failure: 6 callbacks suppressed
[ 1120.891243] btrfs read error corrected: ino 1 off 16956600320 (dev /dev/sdb sector 2901016)
[ 1124.851937] parent transid verify failed on 16977842176 wanted 13187 found 12814
[ 1124.885429] btrfs read error corrected: ino 1 off 16977842176 (dev /dev/sdb sector 2921768)
```

This is my BTRFS setup. RAID10 across 4x3TB HDD:

```
$ sudo btrfs filesystem df /mnt/btrfs
Data, RAID10: total=136.00GiB, used=134.70GiB
System, RAID10: total=64.00MiB, used=20.00KiB
System, single: total=4.00MiB, used=0.00
Metadata, RAID10: total=1.00GiB, used=363.21MiB

$ sudo btrfs filesystem show /mnt/btrfs
Label: none  uuid: <UUID>
    Total devices 4 FS bytes used 135.05GiB
    devid    1 size 2.73TiB used 68.54GiB path /dev/sda
    devid    2 size 2.73TiB used 68.53GiB path /dev/sdb
    devid    3 size 2.73TiB used 68.53GiB path /dev/sdc
    devid    4 size 2.73TiB used 68.53GiB path /dev/sdd
```

And I noticed that the device stats from BTRFS were ...odd...:

```
$ sudo btrfs device stats /mnt/btrfs
[/dev/sda].write_io_errs   0
[/dev/sda].read_io_errs    0
[/dev/sda].flush_io_errs   0
[/dev/sda].corruption_errs 0
[/dev/sda].generation_errs 0
[/dev/sdb].write_io_errs   207275
[/dev/sdb].read_io_errs    127287
[/dev/sdb].flush_io_errs   0
[/dev/sdb].corruption_errs 0
[/dev/sdb].generation_errs 0
[/dev/sdc].write_io_errs   0
[/dev/sdc].read_io_errs    0
[/dev/sdc].flush_io_errs   0
[/dev/sdc].corruption_errs 0
[/dev/sdc].generation_errs 0
[/dev/sdd].write_io_errs   0
[/dev/sdd].read_io_errs    0
[/dev/sdd].flush_io_errs   0
[/dev/sdd].corruption_errs 0
[/dev/sdd].generation_errs 0
```

I've ordered myself a spare 3TB HDD just in case, but can I safely assume that `/dev/sdb` is dead? I just found it a little odd that BTRFS was reporting `[/dev/sdb].corruption_errs 0`.

Is there a universally accepted way of proving that a HDD is dead in a BTRFS RAID array?

Comment: Thanks for the `badblocks` suggestion. I've begun a read-only test on `/dev/sdb`. Reason for read-only is because it's still being used by BTRFS and I'm not sure that running `badblocks` with `-n` would stop me if it doesn't support BTRFS in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have seen similar performance degradations on my server here at home (running RAID-6 with Btrfs on top). It has proven one of the drives on three occasions.

The first thing I do is run `smartctl` for each drive. Then for the failing drive I notice the number of Raw errors:

```
smartctl -x /dev/sdf | fgrep Raw
```

to keep track of those. I have one drive that once showed a few errors but has been stable over the last 9 months after resetting the cabling. Not sure why, but I do consider that one "not yet dead".

If error counts grow again, I remove the drive and bring in replacement (I can live with the risk of one of the two extra drives in my RAID-6 being off line for half a day).

Comment: Not too much difference. `/dev/sda: 115282712
/dev/sdb: 146960040
/dev/sdc: 134936032
/dev/sdd: 159359440`

Comment: Is that the `RAW_VALUE` last entry of the line) of the `Raw_Read_Error_Rate` you are getting? They are 0 for all my drives except for the not dead yet one (which is at 46095). Most importantly IMO is that that those numbers should not grow.

Comment: Yes these numbers are `Raw_Read_Error_Rate`->`RAW_VALUE`.

Comment: Those seem high to me for any system. But make sure you get a second opinion on that before ordering new hardware ;-)

Comment: I've done some reading on smartctl reports and now know a bit more. It seems that the most important values on the `Raw_Read_Error_Rate` row are `VALUE`, `WORST` and `THRESH`. `VALUE` is where the drive is currently at - 200 being pretty-much-perfect and 1 being abject-failure. `WORST` tells you how bad the drive has got in the past - so it will never be higher than `VALUE`, uses the same scale. `THRESH` is the lowest number that the manufacturer lets the drive get to before they consider it 'failed'. So, 200 being perfect and 1 being super-failed, `/dev/sdb` is sitting at 110. `THRESH` = 6

Comment: I'd be interested to know what your possibly dodgey drive is reporting these three values as!

Comment: @Socceroos `ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE`   
`      1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR-K   154   001   051    Past 46095`